# 2 Navigation widgets with distinct style/structure on the same page in Orchard?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

I am working on a theme for Orchard CMS that uses 2 different navigation menu widgets on the same page; a "main menu" in the header part of the page, and another menu in the footer.

Both menus (will) have a different DOM structure and different styles.

I figured out that by creating a Menu.cshtml in my theme's View/ folder I could overwrite the way menus are rendered, and altered it to fit the way I need the main nav menu in the header to be.

Now I want to add the footer menu, but it uses the same Menu.cshtml as template which completely breaks the footer (this can **not** be fixed simply by messing around with CSS).

Is there any way I can make the 2 widgets use different templates? For example have the second widget use Menu-Footer.cshtml instead of Menu.cshtml?

Comment: You can use the Content Item Name to create an alternate for the footer Menu. In the edit page for the menu content item specify the name (i.e. footer). Then create a template named Menu-footer.cshtml, and place the custom html on that template.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sadly this doesn't seem to work. I set the title (there is no name attribute, only title) of the navigation to "TestFooter" and created the Menu-TestFooter.cshtml, but the normal Menu.cshtml is still being used. I learned that I could overwrite (alternate?) the widget by given it the name "TestFooterWidget" and create a Widget-Name-TestFooterWidget.cshtml, but I don't know how to correctly call the Navigation from within the Widget alternate (I'm pretty new to MVC and Orchard), just directly copying the normal Menu.cshtml content for example doesn't work...

Comment: You define a ContentItem for that Menu, use that Name for the alternate

Answer (score 0):

Enable widget alternates and shape tracer. You'll see new alternates for all your widgets that you can use in your theme to get the exact result you want. Don't forget to disable shape tracing when you're done.